# Using A* with target ouside graph

Tags: python, algorithm, a-star, heuristics

My goal is to find the shortest path between A and B but B might be outside of the known graph. Currently my cost function works perfectly and heuristics function is 3D euclidean.

To solve the problem of target might be outside of the graph, I've tried to exit the algorithm when priority value stopped changing a certain time but that didn't worked. The algorithm spitted out a random path.

The reason why I don't select a node that is closest to the target is that if I select that algorithm will try to reach that point for certain. In my application I will rerun the algorithm when new information comes (i.e. update to the graph that might include the target).

So what I need is to find a path that is closest to target outside graph with least cost. I don't expect a code or whatsoever as an answer but any comment on how this kind of problem might be solved is greatly appreciated.

Below, I've added my A* implementation, PriorityQueue is just an wrapper for heapq.

```py
def a_star_search(mesh, start, goal):
    frontier = PriorityQueue()
    frontier.put(start, 0)
    came_from = {}
    cost_so_far = {}
    came_from[start] = None
    cost_so_far[start] = 0

    while not frontier.empty():
        current = frontier.get()

        if current == goal:
            break

        for i, next in enumerate(list(mesh.neighbors(current))):
            new_cost = cost_so_far[current] + mesh.cost(current, next)
            if next not in cost_so_far or new_cost < cost_so_far[next]:
                cost_so_far[next] = new_cost
                priority = new_cost + mesh.heuristic(next, goal) / mesh.unit
                frontier.put(next, priority)
                came_from[next] = current

    return came_from, cost_so_far
```

Example result when target is inside graph
[image: Example result when target is inside graph]

Comment: What's the mechanism for updating the graph? It doesn't seem like getting to the point closest to the target in the known graph would guarantee an optimal solution once the graph is revealed.

Comment: Yes, I don't think it will produce the optimum solution. I would like to update the graph when the agent is near the edge of the known graph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does it even *mean* to be "close" to something that's not in the graph? If the target node could appear anywhere, then there's no point in precomputing anything because you'll have to start over after it appears. If you know where it will eventually appear, then add it to the graph now and compute your path, then truncate the result at the edge of the (currently) known graph.

Comment: Well, target location is known but it isn't inside the boundaries of the graph.

Comment: My point is that you are implying that "outside the graph" has a location that you can "move towards" somehow, which doesn't make sense. The graph is an abstract representation of the nodes and their connections. There is no notion of "location", only the relationship of one node to another. Something outside the graph has no relationship. There's no way to move closer towards it.

Comment: Here's an analogy. Imagine you're computing paths between wikipedia pages. You start at some arbitrary page and want to reach a target page by following links. Now... I want you to start at the "Philosophy" page and tell me how many hops are needed to get to a page I'm going to write next year.  Not only can you not answer the question, but you can't even *start* because the *very first hop* depends on the topic, which you don't know yet. All pages are equally "close" to it.

Comment: Nice analogy. You are right. There are couple of dynamic path planners like D* Lite but it depends on the goal node to be connected to the initial map somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Can you just add `goal` to your graph (connected to every other node, presumably using whatever distance-metric your mesh used)?  Or if you don't want to modify the mesh data-structure, you could just loop over `list(mesh.neighbors(current))+goal` (after updating `new_cost = …` to handle that situation).

Apologies if I've misunderstood something, and this doesn't apply at all…

Comment: I've tried this method but I couldn't figure out when to terminate the algorithm. Since it will never reach the target without graph updated. I've added cost as `float("inf")` for the edge connecting to the target in every known node.

Answer (score 0):

You can minimize the cost of reaching a node plus the estimated cost of reaching the target from that node. It won't be guaranteed to be optimal once you know the full grid, but depending on your heuristic it should be a reasonable guess.